# Something locking change camera

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make the player change from "LockFirstPerson" to "Classic", but it isn't working. The fuction works and I used `print("Tried to enable classic")` which did work. The Roblox documentation and the answer on the devForum tells me it should work so something is locking it.
This is my code right now:

```
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
local Character = script.Parent
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    print("Tried to enable classic")
    player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 15 --Zoom distance
    player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
    Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
    player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 0.5
end)
```

If I try this, I get this error: `Workspace.Tibbiedo1.LocalScript:2: attempt to index nil with 'CameraType'`, so defining the camera isn't working either.

I've tried a lot of different scripts, but none of them work:

1. Changing the `Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom` to `local Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom`
2. Removing the `Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom` completely

Answer (score 1):

```
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local Camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
local Character = script.Parent
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    print("Tried to enable classic")
    player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 15 --Zoom distance
    player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
    Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
    player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 0.5
end)
```

Comment: This should work, because I got no errors, but it still doesn't, so something is still blocking it.

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that configure the camera settings?

Comment: Yes, when you select a weapon, you go into the game and it will lock you into first person.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to lock into first person and you don't have any need for the camera to be [Scriptable](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/enums/CameraType), then you can try this (assuming this is a StarterCharacterScript):

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = players.LocalPlayer

player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.LockFirstPerson

local char = player.Character

if not char or not char.Parent then
    char = player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
end

local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
end)
```